# Authorize.net maven dependency conflict with YaHP Pdf creator

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, authorize.net, html-pdf

I am working on a project that uses :

1. Authorize.net as a payment gateway and
2. YaHP converter to convert HTML pages to PDF

   Below is my pom's portion of YaHP dependencies :

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.allcolor.yahp</groupId>
       <artifactId>yahp-internal</artifactId>
       <version>1.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
       <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
       <version>R8pre2</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
       <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.7</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
       <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>net.sf.jtidy</groupId>
       <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
       <version>r938</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.16</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.allcolor.shanidom</groupId>
       <artifactId>shani-parser</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.17-patched-yahp-1.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
       <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
       <version>2.0.2</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>xerces</groupId>
       <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
       <version>2.11.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

and here is the Authorize.net dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.authorize</groupId>
        <artifactId>anet-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

The problem I am facing is, YaHP specific libraries are causing some unknown trouble in Authorize.net initialization.

Here is the snippet code ff initialization of Authorize.net :

```
GetHostedPaymentPageRequest apiRequest = new GetHostedPaymentPageRequest();
    apiRequest.setTransactionRequest(txnRequest);
    apiRequest.setHostedPaymentSettings(alist);

    GetHostedPaymentPageController controller = new GetHostedPaymentPageController(apiRequest);
    controller.execute();

    GetHostedPaymentPageResponse response = new GetHostedPaymentPageResponse();
    response = controller.getApiResponse();
    if (response != null) {
        if (response.getMessages().getResultCode() == MessageTypeEnum.OK) {

            System.out.println(response.getMessages().getMessage().get(0).getCode());
            System.out.println(response.getMessages().getMessage().get(0).getText());
            System.out.println("Payment request token :" + response.getToken());
            return response.getToken();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to get hosted payment page " + response.getMessages().getResultCode());

        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("ess" + response);
    }
```

Whenever I comment the YaHP related particular portion in pom.xml, I get a response token in my **GetHostedPaymentPageResponse response** object. But when I uncomment those dependencies, it throws a **null** !

Surprising, but this is literally the case.

Can anyone tell me how to make both compatible or atleast find a workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A weird scenario I noticed was changing the order of maven dependencies actually worked and provided the token needed.

Apart from that, the iText dependency version was also causing problem. Tweaking it made everything go on a happy path.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jtidy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
    <version>r938</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
    <version>R8pre2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.allcolor.shanidom</groupId>
    <artifactId>shani-parser</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.17-patched-yahp-1.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.allcolor.yahp</groupId>
    <artifactId>yahp-internal</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```